# Non-clickable parent menu with weebly?

Tags: html, css, weebly

First of all, my site is vitasino.com so that you can do these steps together with me and find out why I am an idiot

Ok, according to

weeblytricks.weebly.com/how-to-make-a-parent-menu-item-non-clickable.html

I am supposed to first right click on your navigation, click "Inspect Element", and find the div that highlights your entire navigation menu.

- Did that and found that the div id is "topnav"

Now, step two is editing the CSS and add the code

/* Deactivated Menu Links
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
."div name" .wsite-nav-4 a {pointer-events: none;}
```

- So I did that and the the parents I want to be unclickable are "Services", "Wholesale markets", "Manufcaturing" and "more". In other words it should be menu items 2,3,4,7 right? So I add the code:

/* Deactivated Menu Links
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
.topnav .wsite-nav-2 a, .wsite-nav-3 a, .wsite-nav-4 a, .wsite-nav-7 a {pointer-events: none;}
```

Should be correct, right? WRONG!

Services are still clickable, Wholesale markets are still clickable, but manufcaturing and fairs are working (althought I dont want fairs to be unclickable.)

What is wrong?

Comment: how does this related to solving your coding problems?

Comment: Services are need to use selector `.wsite-nav-1 a`. right?

Comment: Mosh Feu, I dont understand what you mean.